# I have to login with multiple users and like or dislike the post using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

[image]My website is like Facebook. I need to login with multiple users and like the post from all the logins. Now using JMeter i can able to successfully login with multiple users but i can't like it from all the logins.I have recorded the script to like the post from one login. Please assist how can i achieve this. I am attaching my HTTP Request below.

Answer (score 0):

Normally "like" is a HTTP Request which should be implemented via the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler so you need either create the relevant request manually or simply record it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

Once done you might need to perform the [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)  - the process of identifying dynamic parts of the requests, using [Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to convert the values into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) with the recorded hard-coded values with dynamic variables.

Check the request and response details using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and if you're happy with what your test is doing you can start [adding more virtual users](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) to check how does your application under test behave under the load.